# Trying to make forgot password page. Giving error I don't understand

Tags: php, email, web

I am making a website with a forgot password script. The script send the user a temporary 8 digit passcode, which I am randomly generating. I wrote the code and spent quite some time debugging it, but I still get a server error. I am not sure what the error in the code is, and I know it's not in the server because there is no console message.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

    include '../conn.php';

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["email"]);

    $check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
    $check_result = mysqli_query($conn, $check_query);
    $check_rows = mysqli_num_rows($check_result);

    $allchars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'];
    $temppwd = "";
    for ($x = 1, $x < 9, $x++) {
        $ranodmnum = rand(1, 36);
        $temppwd = $temppwd + $allchars[$randnum];
    }

    function sendMail($to) {
        $subject = "Password Reset Request for Pinder";
        $msg = "You have requsted to reset your password for Pinder. This is your temporary password: " + $temppwd + "You will have to change it next time you login.";
        mail($to, $subject, $msg);
    }

    if ($check_rows > 0) {
        sendMail($email);

    } else {
        echo "Sorry, but there is no account associated with that email address!";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Hi - can you access the server message? Or put some additional debug statements on the server side. Without the server message it's harder to work out what is going wrong.

Comment: shouldn't `$ranodmnum = rand(1, 36); $temppwd = $temppwd + $allchars[$randnum];` have same variable name? I mean `$ranodmnum` and `$allchars[$randnum]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script is failing because you have a syntax error: your `for` statement have commas, when they should have semicolons.

There are two ways you can debug problems like this.

First, if you can run php on your own computer, then, you can run `php -l filename.php` and it will check the syntax for you. (This is what I did for your code.)

Also, you should turn error logging on. In your `php.ini` file (or `.htaccess`, as may be appropriate), you will want to enable [log_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors). If this is a development site, then you may also want to enable [display_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors). (But *do not* enable `display_errors` on a production site; this can leak security-related information to the world.) That way, you will be able to see syntax errors in your webserver's logs.